# I want to create a vector by using values of variables from a dataframe

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(cust_id=1:5, 
                   a=c(10,20,30,40,50), 
                   b=c(5,10,15,20,25), 
                   c=c(20,40,60,80,100),
                   d=c(2,4,6,8,10))

vect <- c(a*2,b*3,c*4,d*5)
```

*here I need to get values of a,b,c,d from the dataset for each cust_id (1:5) as a vector, then multiply them by 2,3,4,5 which are constants*

```
vect <- c(40*2,20*3,80*4,8*5)
```

> *Note: vect is a vector, I need output in vector form.
>
> a,b,c,d are the values of variables from data for each cust_id

Comment: ## I am looking for a function which can call values of a,b,c,d and gets
##multiplied by respective values and should get stored in that vector
##eg: when I call cust_id as 4 I should get a vector as below
##I think I need a function whose input value is cust_id.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I find it difficult to understand your question. Please read: **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. As a start you could consider re-opening your question, adding the information in the comment. Ideally you define your input and your desired output.

Comment: bit unclear. but if you want a vector you can use `with(data, c(a*2,b*3,c*4,d*5))` or if wanting to multiply columns then `with(data, cbind(a*2,b*3,c*4,d*5))` (change cbind to dataframe to suit your needs)

Comment: Hi @KoenV&@user20650 Sorry for my unclear question I made changes to it. @user20650 by making small changes to your code helped me  to get the  answer> Thank you very much

Comment: You want to take the **vectorized dot-product of a matrix by a vector**. And you also want to propagate your `cust_id` column: it's simplest to slice it off, then cbind it separately back into the result. Having an explicit `cust_id` column inside `data` is actually making your life harder; if it was just a row-index, it would get handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `crossprod` (if we need to multiply and then `sum`)

```
crossprod(t(data[-1]), 2:5)
```

If it is only need to multiply by corresponding columns with vector

```
sweep(data[-1], 2, 2:5, "*")
```

---

Or with `mapply`

```
mapply(`*`, data[-1], 2:5)
```

Comment: Hi akrun, sorry for my unclear question. I have made few modifications. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take the **vectorized dot-product of a matrix by a vector**:

```
as.matrix(data[,c('a','b','c','d')]) %*% c(2,3,4,5)

     [,1]
[1,]  125
[2,]  250
[3,]  375
[4,]  500
```

and since you want to also propagate your `cust_id` column, it's simplest to slice off the `cust_id` column of your input dataframe, then cbind it separately back into the result:

```
df.out <- data.frame(cust_id = data[,'cust_id'],
                     result = as.matrix(data[,c('a','b','c','d')]) %*% c(2,3,4,5))

  cust_id result
1       1    125
2       2    250
3       3    375
4       4    500
5       5    625
```